# Restrictions on fields of case class as per db spec

Tags: database, scala

I am creating bunch of case classes in scala which I will use to write to db. As the columns in the db has certain restrictions(Length, type, null/not null, etc). How can I enforce the length restriction on my case object fields without checking every field one by one?

Comment: what do you want to do? Can you update your question with more details actually the question is not clearly telling what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RamanMishra, I've edited the question.

Comment: why can't you use requires and put the condidtion on each field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can put the restructions on the fields of case class

```
object Solution1 extends App {

  case class Payload(name: String, id: Int, address: String) {
    require(name.length < 10)
    require(address.length <= 50)
  }

  println(Payload("name5678910", 120, "earth")) // this will give you an erro
  println(Payload("name", 121, "earth"))
}
```

Comment: Another, arguably more complex, option, would be to give a look to [**refined**](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) to move those restrictions to the type level.